# Image Uploading in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, express, multer, serverside-javascript

I am trying to upload image on the server in NodeJS using multer and I was successful in my task but the thing is I want to send back the file object to the client.

### **Here is the some piece of the code**

```
uploadRouter.route('/')
.post(authenticate.verifyUser, authenticate.verifyAdmin, upload.single('imageFile'), (req, res) => {
    res.statusCode = 200;
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    console.log(req);
    res.json(req.file); 
})
```

When I send the request in postman to the server. It is showing 200 status. File is also uploaded on the server but in postman response it's showing blank.
[Here is the screenshot of postman](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xC635.png)

When I logged the **req.file** object it's showing **undefined**

but when I logged **req** object here is what I got

```
IncomingMessage {
.....

    file: {fieldname: 'imageFile', originalname: 'alberto.png', encoding: '7bit', mimetype: 'image/png', destination: 'public/images', …}

.....
}
```

if this file object is inside the **req** object then why I am not able to access by req.file?

Comment: What all is in the `req.file` object?  Is there anything in there that can't be turned into JSON?  As a test, if you change it to just `res.json(req.file.originalname)` does it then work?

Comment: FYI, you don't need to set the statusCode to 200 or the content-type.  Both will be set automatically for you.

Comment: @KrishnadasPC I think he has a different issue. As you can see his `req.file` is not undefined

Comment: when i used this res.json(req.file.originalname) I got this error Cannot read property 'originalname' of undefined

Comment: **Here is full file object** ```file:{ destination:'public/images'
encoding:'7bit'
fieldname:'imageFile'
filename:'alberto.png'
mimetype:'image/png'
originalname:'alberto.png'
path:'public\\images\\alberto.png'
size:25079}```

Comment: This doesn't make sense. It says `Cannot read property 'originalname' of undefined` then how come does it console that file object!

Comment: i just don't know how to send this file object to the client. This object is only showing in ```req``` object. Accessing directly using ```req.file```it is showing undefined

Comment: Try res.json(JSON.stringify(req.file)) and see postman shows up anything

Comment: still same nothing showing on postman

Comment: you can convert image in base64 string and add that string in database